# How to checkout from GitHub tag?

Tags: eclipse, git

I am a user of Subversion. I can easily checkout the tag from svn as like trunk. But I am struggling with GitHub.  I want to checkout from tag and import the project in Eclipse.

[image: SVN Tag checkout]

[image]

After I click checkout, nothing happens.

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen? What does the little checkmark icon on that tag mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, something *did* happen: you checked out the commit at that tag. The thing is, git is so much faster than SVN, it can sometimes *seem* like nothing happened! If you check the files in your working directory, you will see that they indeed reflect the state of the repository at that tag.